# Espresso Webview JavaScriptBridge - NoClassDefFoundError exception

Tags: java, android, webview, android-espresso

I was using Espresso with Android native components and it works as expected, But trying out Espresso Web by accessing web view always fails for API 16 to API 20.

Hereby I've attached exception stack trace,

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.web.JavaScriptBridge
at android.support.test.espresso.web.action.JavascriptEvaluation$ScriptPreparer.apply(JavascriptEvaluation.java:311)
at android.support.test.espresso.web.action.JavascriptEvaluation$SanitizerTask.innerSanity(JavascriptEvaluation.java:163)
at android.support.test.espresso.web.action.JavascriptEvaluation$SanitizerTask.run(JavascriptEvaluation.java:138)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError'
```

**Dependency Gradle file:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.i_visionblog.www.webviewapps"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:3.0.1')
    androidTestImplementation ('com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.1')
    androidTestImplementation ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.0.1')
}
```

**Testcase example:**

```
@Test
public void loginAccount()
{
    onWebView(withId(R.id.weblogin))
            .withElement(findElement(Locator.ID, "username"))
            .perform(clearElement())
            .perform(webKeys("example@example.com"))
            .withElement(findElement(Locator.ID, "password"))
            .perform(webClick())
            .perform(clearElement())
            .perform(webKeys("samplesample"))
            .perform(webClick())
            .withElement(findElement(Locator.ID, "submit_but"))
            .perform(webClick());
    try
    {
        //added 30 seconds delay between ajax request and API request

        Thread.sleep(30000);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When the test case is launched in the emulator, the webview test always fails with the above stacktrace stating class not found exception. It works fine in above API level 21 in the emulators.

**Note** : I've extended MultiDexApplication class already.

Kindly advice or discuss this issue, I have already filed in Issue tracker a month back but no one seems to reply back from Google. [#66876219](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/66876219)